# Ctrl+A, format as table

Tags: vba, excel

I have a 3000 rows by 50 columns dataset in Excel starting in A1.

I recorded and edited a macro that emulates the following: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, Format as table:

```
Dim koosrange As Range
Set koosrange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
koosrange.Select
ActiveSheet.QueryTables("aspectsClean_1").Delete
ActiveSheet.QueryTables("aspectsClean").Delete
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, koosrange, , xlNo).Name = _
    "Table1"
Range("Table1[#All]").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight1"
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ShowTableStyleFirstColumn = True
```

The entire program consists of 3 parts:

1. Import data from *.txt
2. Concatenate item names to only fit in Col A, and move all other data left, to start in Col B
3. Format all data as table (so that it can be filtered, etc.)

When running the program, the following error occurs on `ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, koosrange, , xlNo).Name = _
        "Table1"` (line 6 of the previous code excerpt):

Error: `A table cannot overlap a range that contains a PivotTable report, query results, protected cells or another table`

Comment: importing from .txt, through the Excel import wizard (or same methods through code), can result in a refreshable query. Click on Data ribbon tab > Connections to see the query. If this is the case and you see such a query then post back please - there are workarounds, including deleting the query or importing using another method etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to my comment, if you used the recorder to record Import > From Text File then the method it would be using would be to add a querytable object connected to the text file, then refreshing it.

Depending on some of the circumstances - I am not fully familiar with the different objects at play in this situation - it is necessary to delete, if they were created, both the connection object and the querytable object.

E.g. a recording i did just now churned out:

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;{snipped path}", Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "new  2"
        '+some other properties churned out removed here for conciseness
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

So, add just before the `End With`:

```
    If Not ActiveWorkbook.Connections(.Name) Is Nothing Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Connections(.Name).Delete
    End If
    .Delete
End With
```

Comment: Thanks!

Will try now and update as soon as I'm done

Comment: Let me know if it doesn't work - I have been assuming you used Macro Recorder to record Import from Text File, so if you didn't then...;)

Comment: Sorry I took so long, had to go do something quickly.


Yes, I have used the built-in Macro Recorder to generate the base code, and then did minor edits.

I took a look at the Connections - there was queries. So I deleted them, added `.Delete` before `End With` as you initially suggested (not `.Item(.Count).Delete`), and so far it seems to work

Comment: @user3548534 yeah I was confused a bit - it seems that there are several objects at play with the query and it is perhaps necessary to delete one or the other depending on circumstances (I haven;t worked it out fully yet) - anyway I will edit my answer to hopefully cover the different situations. Glad it helped.